# When I am trying to change the code to an access token, I get this error

Tags: api, pinterest

I am using dirkgroenen pinterest api, so it was perfectly fine for 1 month but now when changing code to an access token I am getting this error

Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/socialwe/public_html/SWT/SMs/pinterestApi/vendor/dirkgroenen/pinterest-api-php/src/Pinterest/Transport/Request.php on line 227

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Exceptions\PinterestException' with message 'Pinterest error (code: 403) with message: Forbidden' in /home/socialwe/public_html/SWT/SMs/pinterestApi/vendor/dirkgroenen/pinterest-api-php/src/Pinterest/Transport/Request.php:227 Stack trace: #0 /home/socialwe/public_html/SWT/SMs/pinterestApi/vendor/dirkgroenen/pinterest-api-php/src/Pinterest/Transport/Request.php(98): DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Transport\Request->execute('POST', 'https://api.pin...', Array) #1 /home/socialwe/public_html/SWT/SMs/pinterestApi/vendor/dirkgroenen/pinterest-api-php/src/Pinterest/Auth/PinterestOAuth.php(143): DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Transport\Request->post('oauth/token', Array) #2 /home/socialwe/public_html/SWT/SMs/pinterestApi/index.php(18): DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Auth\PinterestOAuth->getOAuthToken('dfb587ef87beaaa...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/socialwe/public_html/SWT/SMs/pinterestApi/vendor/dirkgroenen/pinterest-api-php/src/Pinterest/Transport/Request.php on line 227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because my server IP have blocked by pinterest.
Now I have checked it on another server and its working fine there